# CommCare : how can I avoid registration participants that are in a pre defined blacklist?

Tags: commcare, registration

I have a list of people that I don't want the enumerators to register in CommCare registration form (like a blacklist). So my registration form will ask the enumerators to add the first name, last name and birth date of the participants and if any first name, last name and dob matches the ones that are in the blacklist I want a msg to appear for the enumerator saying that this person is in the blacklist please don't register him/her. How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Lookup Table to define the list of participants you want to block and then check the table in the registration form.

For example, if your Lookup Table is called "denylist" and it has fields "firstname", "lastname", "dob", you can put a validation condition on a question or label as follows:

```
count(instance('denylist')/denylist_list/denylist[firstname = /data/firstname][lastname = /data/lastname][dob = /data/dob) = 0
```

Details on how to use Lookup Tables can be found on the [CommCare help site](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Lookup+Tables)

Comment: You mean to add the table as validation condition? if yes can you walk me through the steps please. Thank you so much

Comment: I've updated my response with an example. Note that there is a dedicated forum for CommCare questions at https://forum.dimagi.com/c/users/

Comment: Thank you simon, I posted my question on the forum but I did not receive any answers, sorry for bothering again but I did not fully understand the steps that I need to do, what I understood is that I need to creat a registration form then add question 1 first name, question 2 last name and question 3 dob. Then what exactly should I do? what should the label or next question look like ?